# Javascript how to store predefined function (with arguments)

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Javascript infamous Loop problem?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1451009/javascript-infamous-loop-problem)

I have the following:

```
function test(a,b,c){
    console.log(a+b+c);
}
for (var i=0; i < array.length; i++){
    steps.push(
        function(){ test(array[i].something, array[i].wow, i);}
    );
```

I want to store functions with several parameters, and bind them to buttons later when the DOM is loaded

```
for (var i=0; i<steps.length; i++){
    $('#mydiv li a').eq(i).click(steps[i]);
}
```

It's not really working since steps[i] contains do(array[i].something, array[i].wow, i); instead of do('bob', 'john', 1) for example

I have tried using the .apply javascript function but it will execute in the loop, instead of storing them

Comment: ugly solution would use eval :/

Comment: note the `do` is a reserved javascript name... if you'r using this name in your code, i suggests you to change it to something else.. maybe this is the cause to your bug

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Closures can help you here. Here's one solution to the first bit of code:

```
function do(a,b,c){
    console.log(a+b+c);
}
for (var i=0; i < array.length; i++){
    (function (i) {
        steps.push(
            function(){ do(array[i].something, array[i].wow, i);}
        );
    })(i);
}
```

There's no "block scope" in Javascript, just function scope. With your code, each function you pushed into the `steps` array had a reference to the last value of `i`, not the one it had when the function was pushed into `steps`. Invoking an immediately executing function enables the pushed function to have a value for `i` that doesn't change, because a closure is being created. And this closure has a value for `i` that is independent of the loop's value for `i`, which will be whatever is the last index of `array`.

Comment: why do you need the i parameter in each closure?

Comment: Because that saves a "permanent" value for `i`, that won't change, even though the loop's value for `i` will. It creates an `i` variable that is only visible and modifiable by the function you're pushing into your `steps` array. The `i` contained in the line `})(i);` is passing the loop's `i` into the function. Inside the function, the `i` referred to there is the one and only parameter of the anonymous function. Make sense?

Comment: See [this Stack Overflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work) for more information (on the general subject of JS closures, with references to articles and other content).

Comment: is it test.bind(null, array[i].something, array[i].wow, i);

Comment: You can use `bind`, but there are cross-browswer issues that you have to navigate. `Function.prototype.bind` isn't automatically defined in all browsers. Whereas, closures are an integral part of the language; the closures solution works everywhere. (Note, I believe Prototype inserts this method where it doesn't exist. jQuery's own `.bind` is for setting event handlers. (And it's now quasi-depricated.)

Answer (score 2):

Use `function.bind`.

```
// Create a new function with null for the `this` object, and 1 and 2 for its arguments.
// Unlike `apply`, you shouldn't enclose the arguments in an array.
var fn = someFn.bind(null, 1, 2, 3, 4);
// This is like calling someFn.apply(null, 1, 2, 3, 4);
fn();
```

See the docs [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind). Note under the heading **Compatability**, it explains how to make sure this function will work on all your target browsers (even old verison of IE). You can just copy and paste the code there.

Comment: is it test.bind(null, array[i].something, array[i].wow, i); or test.bind(null, [array[i].something, array[i].wow, i]);

Comment: This method wants the arguments to be listed out as normal: `test.bind(null, array[i].something, array[i].wow)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
//assuming it's always the same function    
for (var i=0; i < array.length; i++){
    $("#mydiv li a").eq(i).on('click',function() {
        // your function here
    });
}
```

Comment: I need to store these click functions (for reuse), either in an array, either using the onlick attribute of <a> tags

Answer (score 0):

```
function doSomething(a,b,c){
    console.log(a+b+c);
}

functionPrepare(func, args, thisarg) {
  return function() { func.apply(thisarg, args); };
)

var steps = [];
for (var i=0; i < array.length; i++) {
  steps.push( 
    functionPrepare(doSomething, [array[i].something, array[i].wow, i]) 
  );
}

// later...    
for (var i=0; i<steps.length; i++) {
  steps[i]();
}
```